# How do i set a strict audio bitrate when encoding?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm encoding with ffmpeg and my audio bitrate varies somewhat, even tho I'm using `-b:a 224K` it differs with +-1 or 2 kb/s in the finished product. Is there a way to set a strict bitrate? My OCD made me write this post.

Here is my encoding parameters:

```
-c:v libx264 -preset fast -profile:v high -level 4.0 -crf 23 -x264opts cabac=1:ref=4:vbv_maxrate=15000:vbv_bufsize=31250 -coder 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24000/1001 -use_editlist 0 -movflags +faststart -g 30 -bf 2 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -c:a aac -b:a 224K -ar 48K -ac 2 -profile:a aac_low
```

Comment: The native AAC encoder doesn't do CBR. It does ABR but can drift. libfdk_aac can do CBR.

Comment: Ah, i see, so if i want to use that i type -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 224K ?

Comment: Yes. Your build should have libfdk_aac linked.

Comment: Hmm it gives me "Unknown encoder libfdk_aac error." and when i google the issue it seems its a type of codec that is non-free and therefore non-redistributable and therefore i must compile it myself.

Comment: For Windows, you can use the [m-ab-s](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite) script to compile ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks! i will look into this and try to make my own build.